# how to pass JavaScript variable value to another JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I need to pass JavaScript variable value to another JavaScript function

```
$("#myTabs form").on('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var linkHref = $(this).parents('.tab-pane').attr('id');
  $('#myLinks li a').removeClass('active');
  $('#myLinks li')
    .find('a[href="#' + linkHref + '"]')
    .parent()
    .next()
    .find('a')
    .tab('show')
    .addClass('active')
    .attr('data-toggle', 'tab');

  $('a.nav-link').not('.active').css('pointer-events', 'none');
  var SAPno = linkHref;
});

$('a.nav-link').not('.active').css('pointer-events', 'none');
```

For Example `var SAPno` value need to the passed to another JavaScript function

```
function GetInfo() {  
  var ID = SAPno;
}
```

Is it possible..

Comment: Yes is possible. Do this anotherFunction(SAPno);

Comment: Define the function with a parameter and pass the variable as an argument to the function when you call it.

Answer (score 5):

you can declare it outside of the function scope

```
var SAPno;

$("#myTabs form").on('submit', function (e) {
   SAPno = linkHref;
});
```

but you have to make sure the place were you declare it is also a available to the getInfo() function

```
var SAPno;

function GetInfo() {
  var ID = SAPno;
}
```

refer to this to understand the [scope](https://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/)

another way that would work is declaring it in the global environment (not a good practice) but it will work..

```
$("#myTabs form").on('submit', function (e) {
   window.SAPno = linkHref;
});

function GetInfo() {
  var ID = window.SAPno;
}
```

which in case of the browser the global object is the window...

Comment: It should also be noted that polluting the `window` global with your own variables is considered bad practice.

Answer (score 3):

To pass a variable to another function, use function parameters.

Change your `GetInfo` function to accept a parameter:

```
function GetInfo(SAPno) {
  var id = SAPno;
}
```

And call it with the `SAPno` parameter (i.e., inside the `submit` function where `SAPno` is defined):

```
// calling context
GetInfo(SAPno);
```

See the [MDN docs for function parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Function_parameters).

Comment: @SurenSrapyan I would assume that `SAPno` is defined within the calling context (i.e., the `submit` function). It doesn't have to be globally scoped if it is passed as a parameter.

Comment: Just a clarification: `SAPno` in `GetInfo(SAPno)` is an argument, not a parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Of course this possible:

if you want SAPno as parameter

```
function GetInfo(SAPno) {
    var id = SAPno;
    somefunction(id);
}
```

if you want SAPno as function

```
function GetInfo(SAPno) {
    var id = SAPno;
    eval(id); // eval is a built-in function that excute javascript from a normal string
}
```